# Descifrar archivo csv con utf-8 encode en pandas , no cambia los caracteres

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8, unicode

intento importar un archivo csv en python con pandas pero aparecen caracteres raros, intente arreglarlo en excel y vi que era codificacion UTF-8, y en excel ya me aparecen bien pero en pandas no :
Asi se ven en excel cuando elijo UTF-8:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en pandas use este codigo :
beer_reviews=pd.read_excel('beer_reviews_descodificato_UTF.xlsx', encoding='utf-8')
y siguen saliendo caracteres raros:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias :D

Comment: Era csv pero lo converti a excel para descodificarlo, y ya despues importarlo a python

Comment: Sería más simple y eficiente parsear directamente el CSV desde pandas que no el Excel, pero para estar seguros de lo que está pasando necesitaríamos poder reproducirlo. Te aconsejo subir el archivo CSV o una parte mínima de él con una de esas lineas a Google Drive o similar y compartir el enlace. Pegarlo aquí no serviría de nada en éste caso.